How to connect a Roland FP-30x to Arturia MiniFuse2 Audio Interface via Line Output from Roland FP-30x
I want to connect a Roland FP-30x to my Audio Interface, so that I can record the audio from my Computer and use  the Roland FP-30x as a midi Device.
I am aware that the Roland has a USB out too but I don't have any free USB slots on my laptop nor the MiniFuse 2(except a USB Hub, which I don't know if it is compatible with the Roland).
The MiniFuse2 Audio Interface has 2 inputs for xlr-mic/line/instrument. I have one free Input left, since on the other input I have my mic connected.
Now to come to my question, which exact cable would I need to connect the Roland FP-30x Line out to my Audio Interface's input Arturia MiniFuse2?
Thanks for the help in advance! :)

If trying if a hub works absolutely isn't an option, you can use a 1/4" mono plug cable (also known as instrument cable or guitar cable) to connect the L/Mono jack on the piano to the free input on the audio interface. Do not select instrument level (the guitar button) on the interface.

does it make a difference if it is a mono plug cable or stereo? Also would this cable be okay in this case ? : https://www.amazon.de/Mono-Stecker-Gitarren-Kabel-Vergoldeten/dp/B003OSXIHW?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&smid=A2X1ST6CC1USDW&th=1

It does make a difference, because the interface has balanced jack inputs and with a stereo cable the other half of balanced signal will be left floating and if you plug it to stereo source, you'll get the channel difference. There is a question about that somewhere on this site but I can't find it. The cable is the correct one, but I wouldn't buy it from third-party Amazon seller since Thomann has both terrible cables at lower price and decent cables from Cordial and Sommer for a couple of € more.

thank you very much for your answer! I decided on this cable from Thomann: https://www.thomann.de/de/cordial_ccfi_15_pp.htm . Will I be able to put the cable right into my Arturia MiniFuse2 and Roland FP-30x without any additional cables whatsoever?
And I have my headset connected to my audio interface, would i be able to hear the piano through my Audio Interface then, instead of the Piano's build in speakers?
Thanks in advance for your answer! :)

@lookawayfromme yes, that cable goes directly between jacks on the back of the piano and on the front of the interface. To hear it from headphones connected to the interface, you need to turn on monitoring on the interface or DAW. The piano speakers may be turned off automatically when there's something plugged to line output or it may be muted from a setting. You need to check the manual. Just read the manual, it's all explained there.
